# count the number of likes using react native and firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

This is the firestore data structure where I was able to store the ids of users who liked it but not able to count the total number of likes.

[image]

I am trying to count and display the total number of likes for a particular post, whereas I was able to store the interactions on the post but I want the total like count as of Insta or FB posts.

```
 const onLikePress = (userId, postId) => {
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection("posts")
            .doc(userId)
            .collection("userPosts")
            .doc(postId)
            .collection("likes")
            .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
            .set({})
    }

const onDislikePress = (userId, postId) => {
    firebase.firestore()
        .collection("posts")
        .doc(userId)
        .collection("userPosts")
        .doc(postId)
        .collection("likes")
        .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .delete()
}

<View style={{flexDirection:"row" , justifyContent:"space-around" , marginTop:4}}>
                            { item.currentUserLike ?
                                (
                                    <TouchableNativeFeedback 
                                    onPress={() => onDislikePress(item.user.uid, item.id)}
                                    >
                                        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="heart" size={24} color="blue" />
                                    </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                                )
                                :
                                (
                                    <TouchableNativeFeedback 
                                    onPress={() => onLikePress(item.user.uid, item.id)} 
                                    >
                                        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="heart-outline" size={24} color="black" />
                                    </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                                  
                                )
                            }
                            <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Comment', { postId: item.id, uid: item.user.uid })}>
                                 <MaterialCommunityIcons name="comment-text-outline" size={24} color="black" />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
    
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => onShare (item.downloadURL)}>
                                     <MaterialCommunityIcons name="share-outline" size={24} color="black" />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                            <Text>{item.likesCount}</Text>

                        </View>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to share the actual Firestore structure, can you edit your post and add the structure? That would make it easier to check how you are storing information of likes and posts.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question now can you take a look and help in finding the soltuions to this problem and thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FieldValue.increment()` for that. Applying to your code all you have to do is this:

```
const onLikePress = (userId, postId) => {
    conts userPosts = firebase.firestore()
                              .collection("posts")
                              .doc(userId)
                              .collection("userPosts")
                              .doc(postId);
        
    userPosts.collection("likes")
             .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
             .set({})
             .then(() => {
                 userPosts.update({
                     likesCont: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
                 });
             })
}

const onDislikePress = (userId, postId) => {
    conts userPosts = firebase.firestore()
                            .collection("posts")
                            .doc(userId)
                            .collection("userPosts")
                            .doc(postId);
        
    userPosts.collection("likes")
             .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
             .delete()
             .then(() => {
                 userPosts.update({
                     likesCont: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1)
                 });
             })
}
```